# "start_instances() only accepts keyword arguments" error in AWS EC2 Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to start an `EC2 instance` using `boto3`. When I execute the below code it works fine

```
import boto3


ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')

class StartInstances:

    def start_ec_instances(self):
        response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=['i-XXXXXXXXXX'])
        return

StartInstances().start_ec_instances()
```

But when I run the code below I get

```
import boto3


ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')

class StartInstances:

    def start_ec_instances(self, instanceid):
        response = ec2client.start_instances(instanceid)
        return

StartInstances().start_ec_instances('InstanceIds=[\'i-XXXXXXXXXX\']')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/ctm-scripting-utils/ec2/start_instances.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       StartInstances().start_ec_instances("InstanceIds=[\'i-XXXXXXXXXX\']")
>   File
>   "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/ctm-scripting-utils/ec2/start_instances.py",
>   line 11, in start_ec_instances
>       response = ec2client.start_instances(instanceids)   File "/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   line 310, in _api_call
>       "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name) TypeError: start_instances() only accepts keyword arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More of a Python question. You are trying to pass a `string`: `'InstanceIds=[\'i-XXXXXXXXXX\']'` instead of `kwargs`: `InstanceIds=[..]`. One possible way to fix is:

```
class StartInstances:
    def start_ec_instances(self, instanceid):
        response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceid])
        return

StartInstances().start_ec_instances('i-XXXXXXXXXX')
```